Does the Hamiltonian always commute with the Time Evolution Operator?
The time evolution operator $U(t, t_0)$ is given as the solution of the equation
$$ i\hbar \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} U(t, t_0) = HU(t, t_0)$$
whether or not the system is conservative. When the system is conservative, the time evolution operator is given by
$$ U(t, t_0) = \text{e}^{-i(t-t_0)H/\hbar} \implies [U(t, t_0), H] = 0.$$
What can be said about the general case, in which $H$ depends on time explicitly?
Specifically:

Do $U(t, t_0)$ and $H$ still commute?
Is $U(t, t_0)$ still unitary?



What can be said about the general case, in which $H$ depends on time explicitly?
Specifically:

Do $U(t, t_0)$ and $H$ still commute?


No, not in general.
In general, you can write $U$ as a time-ordered series :
$$
U(t,t_0) = \mathcal{T}(e^{-i\int_{t_0}^t dt' H(t')})
$$
$$
\equiv 1 -i\int_{t_0}^t dt' H(t') -\int_{t_0}^t dt'\int_{t_0}^{t'} dt'' H(t')H(t'') + \ldots\;,
$$
where I'm setting $\hbar =1$.
So, even at first order the commutator is seen to not necessarily be zero:
$$
[H(t),U(t,t_0)] \approx -i\int_{t_0}^t dt' [H(t), H(t')]\;,
$$
since $H(t)$ and $H(t')$ don't necessarily commute when $H$ depends on time.


Is $U(t, t_0)$ still unitary?


Yes. We still demand that the wavefunction remains normalized throughout time. So, we still have $U$ being unitary. This is because
$$
1 = \langle\psi(t)|\psi(t)\rangle 
= \langle\psi(t_0)|U^\dagger U|\psi(t_0)\rangle \;,
$$
but $t_0$ is arbitrary, so
$$
U^\dagger U = 1
$$
